# Unable to update fragment on dialogframent dismiss

Tags: java, android

I have an activity with ViewPager, each Fragment on the viewPager open a DailogFragment where I can insert an object, when I click on Accept button the DialogFragmnent dismiss and the parent Fragment has to add the info to the Layout. I use interface to communicate with the fragment, but I can't update the Layout on the Fragment. I have tried some solutions with no good results.
The code is list below:

```
public class TransferPickingActivityProduct extends Fragment implements DialogFragmentProducts.DFragmentListener, DialogInterface.OnDismissListener {

    private static final List<PackOperation> packsprod = new ArrayList<>();

    private LinearLayout listprod;

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {

        packsprod.size();

    }

    public void add(Picking pick, FragmentManager fragment, Long idProd) {

        DialogFragmentProducts dFragment = DialogFragmentProducts.newInstance("PRODUCTO", pick.getId(), idProd);
        dFragment.setTargetFragment(TransferPickingActivityProduct.this, 1);

        dFragment.show(fragment, "PRODUCTO");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinishEditDialog(PackOperation packOperation) {
        //Fragment f = fragment;
        packOperation.save();
        packsprod.add(packOperation);
        //View v = f.getView();


    }
}
```

and DialogFragmentProduct:

```
public class DialogFragmentProducts extends DialogFragment {

    View view;

        Picking picking;

    PackOperation pack, packOp;
    Holder holder;
    byte index;
    private static final int ZBAR_SCANNER_REQUEST = 0;

    private Fragment fragment;

    public DialogFragmentProducts(){

    }

    public static DialogFragmentProducts newInstance(String title, Long id, Long idProd) {
        DialogFragmentProducts frag = new DialogFragmentProducts();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title", title);
        args.putLong("picking", id);
        if (idProd!= null)
            args.putLong("producto", idProd);
        else
            args.putLong("producto", -1);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        fragment = getTargetFragment();
        String title = getArguments().getString("title");
        picking = Model.load(Picking.class, getArguments().getLong("picking"));
        Long test = getArguments().getLong("producto");
        if (getArguments().getLong("producto")!=-1) {
            packOp = ListService.getPackOperationbyProduct(String.valueOf(getArguments().getLong("producto"))).get(0);

        }
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment_product, null);

        Inicialize();

        fragment = getTargetFragment();
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle(title)
                .setView(view)
                .setPositiveButton(this.getString(R.string.accept_button),
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int whichButton) {
                                try{
                                    pack.setProductQty(Double.parseDouble((String) qty.getText().toString()));
                                    pack.setPackage(holder.getPackFuente());
                                    pack.setSync(false);

                                    sendBackResult();
                                    ((TransferPickingActivityProduct)getTargetFragment()).onResume();
                                }
                                catch (Exception e){
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.data_entry), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }

                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton(this.getString(R.string.cancel_button),
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int whichButton) {
                                ((TransferPickingActivityProduct)getTargetFragment())
                                        .doNegativeClick();
                                dismiss();
                            }
                        } ).create();

    }

    public interface DFragmentListener {
        void onFinishEditDialog(PackOperation packOperation);
    }

    public void sendBackResult() {

        DFragmentListener listener = (DFragmentListener) getTargetFragment();

        listener.onFinishEditDialog(pack);

        dismiss();
    }

    public void launchScanner(View view) {
        try {
            if (isCameraAvailable()) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(DialogFragmentProducts.this.getContext(), ZBarScannerActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, ZBAR_SCANNER_REQUEST);


                (intent.getStringExtra(ZBarConstants.SCAN_RESULT).equals(null));
                } else {
                Toast.makeText(this.getContext(), this.getString(R.string.available_camera), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(this.getContext(), this.getString(R.string.read_barcode_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public boolean isCameraAvailable() {
        PackageManager pm = DialogFragmentProducts.this.getActivity().getPackageManager();
        return pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case ZBAR_SCANNER_REQUEST:

                if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {

                    String ean13 = data.getStringExtra(ZBarConstants.SCAN_RESULT);
                    Fragment f = getTargetFragment();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState){
        this.setTargetFragment(this, -1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(final DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);
        setTargetFragment(getTargetFragment(), 1);
        Fragment parentFragment = getTargetFragment();
        if (parentFragment instanceof DialogInterface.OnDismissListener) {
            ((DialogInterface.OnDismissListener) parentFragment).onDismiss(dialog);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post code for your `Fragment` and your `DialogFragment`, including specifically the communication between them.

Comment: sorry, I put the code, I can't access to update listprod nor onDimiss or onFinishEditDialog

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should check if you really get data from dialog at parent fragment
 Easy way  Log.d("My debug", ... )

If not see this example below

Call dialog from fragment

```
    DialogFragment fragment = new DialogFragment ;
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    fragment.setTargetFragment(this, REQ_FLAG);
    fragment.show(getFragmentManager(), fragment.getClass().getName());
```

get callback and data after dismiss dialog fragment

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                .....

        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
                .....
             String string = data.getStringExtra("string");
    }
```

In dialog fragment

```
builder.setView(view).setNegativeButton(R.string.btnDel,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.putExtra("string", " Hi ");
                        getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(),
                                Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
                    }
                });
```

After that you should remember that ViewPager create all fragments at the start, you should refresh fragments elements manually

Comment: I tried but I althougth get the text, I can't launch a Toast with the message

Comment: @shadowalker are you getting any error while showing toast?

Comment: yes, it doesn't recognize getContext and thrown an exception

Answer (score 0):

You try to use onDismiss in parent fragment and in DialogFragment. It's a mistake, you have a conflict, it's excessively